# How to include GET & POST data in PHP error log

Tags: php

Is there a way to have `PHP` log errors to a file or email me errors `INCLUDING $_POST[]` & `$_GET[]` and `$_SERVER[]` data?

Right now I get a log of `PHP FATAL` and `WARNING` errors and `404 NOT_FOUND` errors but it's hard to debug some errors without knowing things like user input and the referrer.

Thanks

Comment: Use a [custom error handler](http://php.net/set_error_handler) and [error_log](http://php.net/function.error_log).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
error_log(print_r($_POST, true));
error_log(print_r($_GET, true));
```

Put that into a [custom error handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) and it'll log both for you (the 'true' parameter makes print_r return text instead of outputting it).

You might need to boost the max line length in the error log with [`log_errors_max_len`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors-max-len), as it defaults to 1024 chars and will truncate everything after that (it won't split >1024 char data across multiple lines).

Comment: Used this answer to get a `$response` 500 output from phpunit and it worked well, the error was printed in the terminal when running the test. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP 5 create a custom exception class which will [**extend the native PHP Exception class**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php) and add whatever data collecting / logging methods you like. That way you could easily combine `try {} catch() {}` block with Exceptions and have your own way of controlling how you want to log all data.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the error_log() function. I use that a lot to debug stuff in php.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php

Answer (score -1):

I worked on a telecom project that used CI to handle a Felx based frontend, we hijacked all possible error reporting and wrote a wrapper on syslog functions and used it in our application, the result was we could log whatever data we wanted and the log was visible through system log viewer :-)

Comment: Hint: PHP can log to syslog directly. It's an ini setting.

Comment: Hint: I mentioned we wrote a wrapper on syslog functions, there has to be a reason why some one would write a wrapper and not use the ini files. Please do pay attention to what have been mentioned before you use your power to downvote an answer. Thanks for nothing. :-)

Comment: Well then to whosoever down voted please do comment why would you downvote an answer or a comment, this really helps the other party to learn from the mistake, again thanks for nothing for downvoting without explanation.