# How to dump string variables to a text file

Tags: php

I have a series of variables in my PHP script that are defined via `POST`.

For example:

```
$From = "";
if( isset($_POST['From']) )
{
    $From = $_POST['From'];
}
```

How can I create a log file (not a database, just basic txt) to capture the `POST` values? This is part of a conferencing web app, so there is no way to display the content "on screen". I need to dump it to a file on the server.

Comment: http://uk3.php.net/fwrite

Comment: There is also `error_log("From ".$from)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947358/how-to-include-get-post-data-in-php-error-log

Comment: Are you sure you want to write it to a file? An interactive debugger (like for instance an `xdebug` & netbeans or phpstorm combo) will enable you to set breakpoints, inspect variables, and more, without littering your code with all kind of debug writes. If you really just want to log posts, configuring apache to log the entire request bodies of all requests is also easier then doing it in PHP (but with a little less output format control).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON-encode your array using [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) and store it to a file:

```
$data = json_encode($_POST);
file_put_contents('file.txt', $data);
```

When you want to retrieve the contents, you can  use [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) or similar and then use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) to decode the JSON-string back into an array / object.

Using JSON makes the interchanging of data easier, and you don't need to parse the text file to retrieve information out of it. Just use `json_decode()` and be done with it. However, I suggest you use a database instead of a plain text file to store this information, as it gives you more control.

As *@Wrikken* noted in the comments below, you could use the `FILE_APPEND` flag - it allows you to append the data to the file instead of overwriting it.

```
file_put_contents('file.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: I'd add `, FILE_APPEND`, depending on what the actual need is.

Comment: Thanks, and if I want each post to add as a new line to the same file, how would I do that?

Comment: @alias51: Why do you need to do that?

Comment: Because it's easier to read :) I.e. I want to use FILE_APPEND but have a line break between entries for each `POST`

Comment: @alias51: Oh, you mean linebreks after each JSON-string? In that case, you could simply change `$data` to `$data.PHP_EOL`.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
    $post_dump = print_r($_POST, TRUE);
    $log = fopen('log.txt', 'a');
    fwrite($log, $post_dump);
    fclose($log);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
<?php
  $From = "";
  if( isset($_POST['From']) ){
      $file = fopen("test.txt","w");
      fwrite($file,$From);
      fclose($file);
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
$arr = array();
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value);
{
    $arr[] = $key.'='.$value;
}
file_put_contents('log.txt', implode(',', $arr), FILE_APPEND);
```