# Add URL to error log (Wordpress, Nginx, PHP7)

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, logging, error-handling

I would like to add the URL for every error logged by PHP and Nginx. As the error log gives me the concerned script, the same script is used for many different URLs that have different data sources (remote APIs).

I believe this error comes from certain data from remote API. Having the error URL (browsed by user) would help me identify the concerned data source.

**Nginx**

Nginx error log is enabled, but it just logs Nginx related errors (Google Pagespeed logs). It's strange, as, on many other servers, the Nginx log contains Nginx AND PHP errors. ([log format source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947358/how-to-include-get-post-data-in-php-error-log))

```
nginx.conf
log_format main '$http_x_forwarded_for - $remote_user [$time_local] '
'"$request_method $scheme://$host$request_uri $server_protocol" '
'$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" ["$host" - "$request"]'
'"$http_user_agent" $request_time';
```

**PHP**

As said, PHP log contains PHP errors, but the nginx log_format don't apply on this.

```
php.ini
error_log = /var/log/php-errors.log

www.conf //I've never changed this on any server to manage logs
;php_flag[display_errors] = off
;php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/fpm-php.www.log
;php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
```

**Wordpress**

Enabling the Wordpress debug log seems to stop outputing errors to the PHP error log. I usually disable this, as Nginx contains all errors formated for my needs.

```
wp-config.php
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

In the end, I don't know what to do with all those different log configurations.

Usually:

- My nginx log contains PHP and Nginx logs, and so I'm able to manage log_format from nginx configuration files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not aware of any way to configure the log format of the standard PHP error log. I think you might need to use your own custom error handler for that.

Comment: Thanks. Well as I said, I usually manage to get nginx logging all Nginx and PHP error logs. Meaning that PHP errors are contained in the Nginx error log files, on which I can adapt log_format.

Comment: Maybe by just sending PHP errors to the system’s default logger? http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log

Comment: Well, It would just change the PHP error log file, right? Usually, on other servers, PHP doesn't log anything itself as Nginx is logging everything using my log_format. In the end, I still cannot change PHP log_format to add URL, as I can using Nginx. Thanks anyway.

Comment: When you make PHP pass the info to the syslog, it might be that other processes can then access the info and format it by their own specification.

Comment: Well yes ! It seems to work ! I just commented the `error_log` line in `php.ini`. As the documentation you linked says `If this directive is not set, errors are sent to the SAPI error logger.`. It seems that PHP errors are now logged to the Nginx error log and respect log_format from `nginx.conf`. Thanks a lot @misorude - I'm gonna wait few minuts to see if it works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

@misorude comment helped me to fix this.

Commenting `error_log = /var/log/php-errors.log` in my `php.ini` fixed the issue.

As the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log) that @misorude says:

> If this directive is not set, errors are sent to the SAPI error logger. For example, it is an error log in Apache or stderr in CLI.

Now, all PHP errors are logged into the nginx error log, and the log_format specified in nginx.conf is respected. Feel free to upvote @misorude comment !